# Purpose of function attribute noclone

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

According to `gnu` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) noclone attribute is defined as:

> This function attribute prevents a function from being considered for cloning—a mechanism that produces specialized copies of functions and which is (currently) performed by interprocedural constant propagation.

What does above definition imply about *when* and *where* we should use this function attribute?

Comment: A guess - having a simple function instance aids in debugging, so, the only place to install breakpoint and/or modify its code on the fly.

Comment: There's an argumented example of it in this clang bug [here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22311) and the original gcc patch [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2009-07/msg01021.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know two use cases of this attribute, both are very specific to gcc. These are:

1. If you take address of a label (GNU extension), the address will
   differ between the function specializations if function body is
   cloned. You should use the attribute if you expect addresses to be
   the same.
2. `__builtin_return_address` may return different return addresses, while without cloning they would be the same.

I advise not to use this attribute and let optimizer do its job.